# Use linq to group by array element

Tags: arrays, linq, group-by

I have data in the following structure which I need to group by Id and Date. Date is a field on an array. I need to sum the amounts for each date grouped by Id at the top level, is this possible with linq?

```
Id 
Number 
MyArray[]
```

MyArray is as follows:

```
[Amount, Date]
```

Trying to use something like this, but it wont work because my second grouping is on an array on the main item

Input:

```
Id Number  MyArray
1    5     [{500.00,2001-03-08}, {200,2001-04-04}, {600, 2001-03-09}] 
2    6     [{700.00,2001-03-08}, {300,2001-03-08}]
1    7     [{400.00,2001-03-08}, {100, 2001-04-04}, {550.00,2001-12-12}]
```

Expected Result:

```
  Id    MyArray
   1    [{500.00+400.00,2001-03-08}, {200+100,2001-04-04}, {600, 2001-03-09}, {550.00,2001-12-12}] 
   2    [{700.00,2001-03-08}, {300,2001-03-08}]

from s in db.Schedules

group s by new {s.empid, s.weekending} into g

select new { g.Key.empid, g.Key.weekending, g.Sum(s => s.hours) };
```

Comment: Could you give use a sample input and desired output?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - i've added in the input and expected result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var results = db.Schedules.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                          .Select(g => new
                                       {
                                           .Id = g.Key,
                                           .Data = g.SelectMany(x => x.MyArray)
                                                    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                                                    .Select(g2 => new { Amount = g2.Sum(x => x.Amount), Date = g2.Key })
                                                    .ToArray()
                                        });
```

Comment: Thanks! is it possible for me to set .Data to a new MyArray type? so the anonymous object has a MyArray on it instead of array [DateTime, Decimal]

Comment: This does not get the expected result, or the example of the OP is wrong.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - If I just needed to group by the Date on MyArray and not the Id, could I do that? struggling to get it to work